# Get IQueryable object items in ASPNET MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Source is a not strongly type IQueryable returned by a Dynamic Linq Select.
As a result in View I have:

[image]

As they are not strongly typed I cannot manage to access (and correctly display) objects `code` and `name_en` (please note the reason I am using a dynamic linq select is column names vary from select to select).
I tried to access values by their index, `item[0], item[1]` but I get a `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`error.

Comment: What is the source then? Why not make it a strongly typed list instead?

Comment: You have to provide relevant code, like your model class and how you are executing the query.

Comment: Sure in case there is no easy way to access above object at view level I will try and change code behind. Is that you are saying?

Comment: @Luke you have to provide relevant code *to us*. I mean that we cannot help you if you do not add your code (model class, dynamic linq code, etc.) to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use property names if you already know them like so

```
item.GetType().GetProperty("code").GetValue(item);
```

Or just use more reflection and render all properties this object have.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        @{
            var type = item.GetType();
            var props = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                <td>
                    @p.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @type.GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(item);
                </td>
            }
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Of course you can loop through all properties and then just check and exclude some properties, like Id or other private data, which you would not like to render.

Comment: Thanks Mantas, you went right to the point, correctly understanding the question, replying in substance and solving the problem. 5 stars!

Comment: Sometimes it is very annoying to be stuck and not to get results you want. Glad you solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your Model class as is, you may just use dynamic objects in your view:

```
@foreach (dynamic item in Model.languageTable)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.code</td>
        <td>@item.name_en</td>
    </tr>
}
```